# What is the difference between ていたつもりだったが and ているつもりだったが?

Tags: grammar

1.リビングで眠ってしまった琴里をおぶって部屋に運ぶのは日常茶飯事であったし、女の子を背負うのには**慣れているつもりだったが**......やはり、少し感覚が異なった。琴里よりも少しだけ重たい体重が、女の子特有の柔らかな感触をはっきりと伝えてくる。

Context: 士道 is carrying his classmate 折紙, who is in hospital, on his back. He isn’t having the same feeling as he does when he carries 琴里, his sister.

2.折紙は、自分の判断が甘かったことを知った。
剣压の余波で、おおよその威力を**推し量っていたつもりだったが**ーー違う。明らかに、世界が、違う。

Context: 折紙 is fighting a 精霊. The latter uses a sword that has tremendous power. 折紙 guessed the power wrongly previously.

Hi. Can we use ていたつもりだったが and ているつもりだったが interchangeably in both examples? If we can, what is the difference between ていたつもりだったが and ているつもりだったが in both examples? Is ているつもりだったが used only for durative verbs while ていたつもりだったが only for punctual verbs?

(Both seem to mean “XX thought..., but......”).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions are same in meaning of "wrong estimation".
But there are difference in what their basis or criteria comes from.

- "ていたつもりだったが"

This is expression of wrong estimation or confirmation and their basis come from one's past EXPERIENCE or ACTION.

(e.g. 「太郎はドアに鍵をかけていたつもりだったが、泥棒に入られた」- "Taro made locked the door, but robbed.

- "ているつもりだったが"

This is expression of wrong estimation or confirmation and their basis come from one's present HABIT.

(e.g. 「太郎は毎日一生懸命練習しているつもりだったが、試合に負けた。」- Taro practices hard every day, but he lost.